# Fatal error when trying to stop timer object in swift

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-5

I'm currently working on a stop watch for an Apple Watch. The watch has two interfaces and two controllers. `TimerController` and `SwitchController`. The `TimerController` runs the timer. I'm trying stop the time object from the `SwitchController` and have therefore made an function that stops the timer in my `TimerController` which i can reach in the `SwitchController`. Problem is that i get a fatal error in the `TimerController`, and i cant figure out why?

the function `timeStopp()` in the `timerController` returns the error:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

**See This Image!**

[The interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cUqH.jpg)

**Errors**

SwipeController
[Swipe error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUpMR.jpg)

TimeController
[time error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksxp6.jpg)
[time error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyE6Q.jpg)

**FrameWork** 
[Do i type it in here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3KFq.jpg)

**TimerController**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class TimerController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var timerOutlet: WKInterfaceTimer!

    var myTimer : Timer?
    var duration : TimeInterval = 45.0 //arbitrary number. 45 seconds

    var isPaused = false //flag to determine if it is paused or not
    var elapsedTime : TimeInterval = 0.0 //time that has passed between 
    pause/resume
    var startTime = NSDate()
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        start_timer()   
        timerOutlet.setTextColor(UIColor.red)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    func start_timer() {
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: duration, target: 
        self,selector: Selector(("timerDone")), userInfo: nil, repeats: 
        false)
        timerOutlet.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: duration ) as 
        Date)
        timerOutlet.start()
    }
    func timerDone(){
        //timer done counting down
    }
    @IBAction func pauseResumePressed() {
        //timer is paused. so unpause it and resume countdown
        if isPaused{
            isPaused = false
            myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: duration - 
            elapsedTime, target: self, selector: 
            Selector(("timerDone")), userInfo: 
            nil, repeats: false)
            timerOutlet.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: duration - 
            elapsedTime) as Date)
            timerOutlet.start()
            startTime = NSDate()
            //pauseResumeButton.setTitle("Pause")

        }
            //pause the timer
        else{
            isPaused = true

            //get how much time has passed before they paused it
            let paused = NSDate()
            elapsedTime += paused.timeIntervalSince(startTime as Date)

            //stop watchkit timer on the screen
            timerOutlet.stop()

            //stop the ticking of the internal timer
            myTimer!.invalidate()

            //do whatever UI changes you need to
            //pauseResumeButton.setTitle("Resume")
        }
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to 
        be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no 
        longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

**UPDATED** **SwipeController**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class SwipeController: WKInterfaceController {

    //@IBOutlet weak var myTimer: WKInterfaceTimer!
    var timer = TimerController()

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to 
be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no 
longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    /stopp call is made here
    @IBAction func PauseButton() {
       timer.pauseResumePressed()
    }

}
```

Comment: Do include the code from `SwitchController` that tries to call `timeStopp()`

Comment: How are you presenting `TimerController`? Is it done through a segue?

Comment: `@IBOutlet` will be nil until you don't present the view. You just initialise the `TimerController` and all of its `controls` will be nil.

Comment: Use proper delegation, `var timer = TimerController()` won't give you a reference to the presenting view controller, and its methods

Comment: how do i get the reference @Carpsen90 ?? I´m very new to Swift...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

Import Notification Center first. 
Click on your project in the Project Navigator on the left side. In General go to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Click on the + button and **Search for Notification Center, then add the framework**

[image: Screen]

> **Delete the whole `TimerViewController` and paste it with this: https://gist.github.com/rawandahmad698/a0095e584eaa4df278a23c92e71cca62**
>
> **Delete the whole `SwipeViewController` and paste it with this: https://gist.github.com/rawandahmad698/9ac0b7a411b7e88ff44068938a0b250a**

First. add this at the end of your code to your `TimerController`:

```
import NotificationCenter
extension Notification.Name {
     static let stopTimer = Notification.Name("stopTimer")
}
```

After that. on your `SwipeController` edit this line:

```
@IBAction func PauseButton() {
    // Post notification:
    let userInfo = ["foo": 1, "bar": "baz"] as [String: Any] // you could also transfer data

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .stopTimer, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

Finally. on your `TimerController` add this to `willActivate()`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stop_timer(notification:)), name: .stopTimer, object: nil)
```

DONT FORGET: add this below `willActivate()`

```
func stop_timer(notification:NSNotification) {

    // Timer is paused. so unpause it and resume countdown
    if isPaused {
        isPaused = false
        timerOutlet.start()
        startTime = NSDate()

    } else {
        isPaused = true

        // Stop watchkit timer on the screen
        timerOutlet.stop()

        // Stop the ticking of the internal timer
        myTimer!.invalidate()

        // Do whatever UI changes you need to

    }

}
```

---

#### Old Solution

You can't invalidate a timer that hasn't been scheduled yet. 
First add an NSTimer:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class TimerController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var timerOutlet: WKInterfaceTimer!
    var myTimer : NSTimer?
    var duration : NSTimeInterval = 45.0 //arbitrary number. 45 seconds

    // UPDATE
     var isPaused = false //flag to determine if it is paused or not
      var elapsedTime : NSTimeInterval = 0.0 //time that has passed between pause/resume
    var startTime = NSDate()
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        timerOutlet.setTextColor(UIColor.red)


        // Configure interface objects here.
}
```

Pause the timer using a button:

```
 @IBAction func pauseResumePressed() {
    //timer is paused. so unpause it and resume countdown
    if isPaused{
        isPaused = false
        myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(duration - elapsedTime, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDone"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        timerOutlet.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: duration - elapsedTime))
        timerOutlet.start()
        startTime = NSDate()
        pauseResumeButton.setTitle("Pause")


      }
      //pause the timer
      else{
            isPaused = true

            //get how much time has passed before they paused it
            let paused = NSDate()
            elapsedTime += paused.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)

            //stop watchkit timer on the screen
            timerOutlet.stop()

            //stop the ticking of the internal timer
            myTimer!.invalidate()

            //do whatever UI changes you need to
            pauseResumeButton.setTitle("Resume")
        }
    }
```

Start the timer:

```
func start_timer() {
     myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(duration, target: self,selector: Selector("timerDone"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
     timerOutlet.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: duration ))
     timerOutlet.start()
}
```

When the `timer` completes. This block gets invoked

```
func timerDone(){
       //timer done counting down
}
```